# Auto adjust label positions

Tags: lightningchart

I am adding custom chart labels using **setResultTableFormatter**

```
 line[key].setResultTableFormatter((builder, series, xValue, yValue) => {
     return builder
            .addRow(name)
            .addRow(yValue.toFixed(2))
            .addRow(timedata[xValue.toFixed(0)])

});
```

This is working fine in Dashboards with 4 charts.But if there is 6 charts in  dashboard..Label is hiding to the right side , If i place cursor to right side of the page.PLease check below example.

[image]

Comment: I didn't exactly understand the part about 4 layouts working fine, and 6 layouts not working. Could you provide full screenshot of a working scenario, and not working scenario? I understand that setting padding is not always an ideal solution.

Comment: I mean if there is dashboards with 4 charts its working fine . and not working if there is 6 charts in dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use chart.setPadding to add padding on the problematic sides

```
chart.setPadding({ right: 60 })
```

Comment: no does not work when there is 6 charts even if I set padding on right.. label is going away from screen... but if I dont formatTable it is displaying correctly in screen.Please note the title of label lenghty text..which is 8 to 10 words.

Comment: Actually looks like its bug  try to create chart and minimize it... if the label text is lengthier than chart width its hiding on right side.. you can test it with this string --> "This is test label which is very lengthy and width is greater than the chart 123456"

Comment: Could you please edit the question with a code snippet that creates the problematic dashboard and formats the table? If at all possible, with screenshot attached.

Comment: I will try to create live demo.